# How to adjust three divs using flex to occupy the exact width of screen?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have three divs side-by-side. The left one should occupy 25% of the screen. The middle one should occupy a fixed size, let's say 50 pixels (that may change). The third one should occupy the remaining space, but not exceed the size of the screen. When I load a big image on it, it exceeds the screen. I have tried `flex: 1 1 auto;` and `flex-shrink: 1;` but both are useless. I want the scrollbar to appear on the `d3` div, not on `body`.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
#d1 {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  width: 25%;
}
#d2 {
  background-color: green;
}
#d3 {
  background-color: blue;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}
#d3a {
  background-color: cyan;
  margin: 1em;
  width: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div id='d1'>
1
</div>
<div id='d2'>
2
</div>
<div id='d3'>
  <div id='d3a'>
  3a
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `overflow: auto;` on last element

Answer (score -2):

The first child has to have no `flex`, and only the width (in %).
The second child will have no `flex` either, and a width in px (since you want it fixed). 
And finally, the third child will have `flex: 1`, in order to take all the space left.

If the image is making the third child wider than the screen, put a `width: 100%`.